# vscode text once a color theme has been applied, it won't change back

Tags: visual-studio-code

I downloaded and some color themes and now I can't change it back. Even when I revert back to the original color theme, all my code just looks highlighted when it is not.

[image]

[edit]

It looks like this is only happening on *.sql files only...

python files look fine to me...

[image]

[edit]

When I open up the Inspector..

[image]

But #1E1E1E is not the color... it looks like it's being highlighted??!?!
[image]

Comment: Open your settings.json (global, workspace, folder), and check if some color customizations were added there.

Comment: I don't think so.... I only have 4 lines.. git, python and terminal related

Comment: this is only happening for *.sql.

Comment: someone please help me.. this is driving me insane!

Comment: What theme did you install before?

Comment: i believe was originally on "Dark+" default theme then changed to "snowflake dark" and changed it back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an option in SQLTools extension. Now I can sleep....

[image]